# How to hide result set decoration in Psql output

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do you hide the column names and row count in the output from psql?

I'm running a SQL query via psql with:

```
psql --user=myuser -d mydb --output=result.txt -c "SELECT * FROM mytable;"
```

and I'm expecting output like:

```
1,abc
2,def
3,xyz
```

but instead I get:

```
id,text
-------
1,abc
2,def
3,xyz
(3 rows)
```

Of course, it's not impossible to filter the top two rows and bottom row out after the fact, but it there a way to do it with only psql? Reading over its manpage, I see options for controlling the field delimiter, but nothing for hiding extraneous output.

Comment: `psql -U username -X -A -w -t -c "select count(*) from yourtable)"` produces just the output: `1`

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can use the `-t` or `--tuples-only` option:

```
psql --user=myuser -d mydb --output=result.txt -t -c "SELECT * FROM mytable;"
```

---

**Edited** (more than a year later) **to add:**

You also might want to check out [the `COPY` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html). I no longer have any PostgreSQL instances handy to test with, but I think you can write something along these lines:

```
psql --user=myuser -d mydb -c "COPY mytable TO 'result.txt' DELIMITER ','"
```

(except that `result.txt` will need to be an absolute path). The `COPY` command also supports a more-intelligent CSV format; see [its documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html).

Comment: alternatively, if you want the header but not the row-count footer, run psql with --pset="footer=off"

Comment: `COPY` can indeed be a valid alternative, but the file will end up on the server, and not on the machine where psql is run...

Comment: @fvu: Good point. I usually ran `psql` *on* the server, so for me that wasn't an issue . . .

Comment: If you want the file to end up on the client filesystem use the psql's **[\COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY)** (i.e. add a backslash in front of COPY command)

Comment: I think @GabrielBurt comment deserves to be a standalone answer. That's exactly what I was looking for to generate a csv with header but without the pesky "`(nnnn rows)`" footer.

Comment: @gabriel-burt comment is the correct answer `--pset="footer=off"`, Gabriel should post an aswer with just that.

Comment: @Merlin: No, his comment is not the correct answer to the OP's question. A lot of people have found it useful, and that's great, but let's not pretend it's something it's not.

Comment: Add the `--no-align`  option to avoid obtaining unneeded whitespace in the output.

Answer (score 33):

You can also redirect output from within psql and use the same option.  Use \o to set the output file, and \t to output tuples only (or `\pset` to turn off just the rowcount "footer").

```
\o /home/flynn/queryout.txt
\t on
SELECT * FROM a_table;
\t off
\o
```

Alternatively,

```
\o /home/flynn/queryout.txt
\pset footer off
. . .
```

Comment: When dumping multi line values I am still getting the `+` character at the end of each line, is there a way to stop this too?

Answer (score 9):

usually [when you want to parse the psql generated output](https://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/working-with-postgresql-on-the-command-line.html) you would want to set the `-A` and `-F` ...

```
    # generate t.col1, t.col2, t.col3 ...
    while read -r c; do test -z "$c" || echo  , $table_name.$c  | \
       perl -ne 's/\n//gm;print' ; \
       done < <(cat << EOF | PGPASSWORD=${postgres_db_useradmin_pw:-} \
       psql -A -F  -v -q -t -X -w -U \
       ${postgres_db_useradmin:-} --port $postgres_db_port --host $postgres_db_host -d \
       $postgres_db_name -v table_name=${table_name:-}
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE 1=1
    AND table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name   =:'table_name'  ;
    EOF
    )
    echo -e "\n\n"
```

You could find example of the full bash call [here](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/qto/blob/master/src/sql/pgsql/scripts/bash/list-table-cols.sh):

Comment: Well done for actually answering the question and winning the "Yet again the best answer is at the bottom of the page" prize.