# how to assign a query result to a shell variable

Tags: sql, shell, unix, sh, variable-assignment

I have an sql query that returns a date.
I call this query from a shell script and would like to assign this value to the variable called datestart (and use it later). Here is my code. Without the datestart assignment the query works fine.

```
#!/bin/sh
firstname="-Upgsql"
dbname="statcoll"
portname="-p5438"
datestart=(psql $firstname $portname $dbname<< EOF
SELECT MIN(latestrefdate) FROM (SELECT MAX(referencedate) AS latestrefdate FROM statistics WHERE transactionname IN(SELECT DISTINCT transactionname FROM statistics WHERE platform = 'Smarties')GROUP BY transactionname) as earliest;
EOF
)
echo $datestart
```

but the result  is this :

```
 Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")").
```

I have no idea where should I insert that closing bracket. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of brackets in variable assignment you need to use `$(...)` for `BASH` or **`...`** for `sh`.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh

firstname="-Upgsql"
dbname="statcoll"
portname="-p5438"
datestart=`psql -t --pset="footer=off" --user="$firstname" --port="$portname" -d "$dbname"<<EOF
SELECT MIN(latestrefdate) FROM (SELECT MAX(referencedate) AS latestrefdate FROM statistics WHERE transactionname IN (SELECT DISTINCT transactionname FROM statistics WHERE platform = 'Smarties') GROUP BY transactionname) as earliest;
EOF
`
echo "$datestart"
```

Comment: I really recommend `$(..)` over backticks, backticks don't work at all when used inside of each other, while nested expressions are fine using `$(..)`

Comment: yes, it almost solved my problem. Instead of the actual date value the content of the header gets assigned to the variable. So I expect something like this '2014-05-23' but got 'min ----- (1 row)' instead

Comment: That is due to column header and footer text. See [this Q&A](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24215/how-to-turn-off-header-only-in-psql-postgresql)

Comment: Also check updated answer and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934264/how-to-hide-result-set-decoration-in-psql-output