# Store value from postgresql in a bash variable

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I'm making an script in bash in what i run a psql query with this:

```
VAR="$(psql -h prov-db-cl -p 5446 -d prov -U prov -c "SELECT value FROM table where query = 'query'")"
```

The problem is the content on `$VAR` is like this:

`value ----------------- result (1 row)`

I just need `result` in my `$VAR` to use it in the rest of the script.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934264/how-to-hide-result-set-decoration-in-psql-output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [store postgresql result in bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242752/store-postgresql-result-in-bash-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VAR=`psql -t -h prov-db-cl -p 5446 -d prov -U prov -c "SELECT value FROM table where query = 'query'"`
```

or

```
VAR=$(psql -t -h prov-db-cl -p 5446 -d prov -U prov -c "SELECT value FROM table where query = 'query'")
```

The `-t` returns only the tuple (data).

[See psql documentation about available options.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

**EDIT**

I've been able to use a subsheel as suggested here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21193276/14673

```
psql -t -h prov-db-cl -p 5446 -d prov -U prov -c "SELECT value FROM table where query = '`echo $VAR`'"
```

Comment: Did you know if type could be a problem when i use this method? I mean i have:
`VAR="$(psql -h prov-db-cl -p 5446 -d prov -U prov -c "SELECT value FROM table1 where query = 'query'")"
psql -h prov-db-cl -p 5446 -d prov -U prov -c "SELECT * FROM table2 where query2 = '$VAR'")`

And is not working the 2nd query, and i know for sure that the `VAR` value exists in the table2, but it just don't found any result. And guessing some type problems because `$VAR` is an integer, but is used like string because the DB logic

Comment: @X3MBoy You can't expand variable into single quotes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192420/shell-bash-how-to-echo-variables-inside-single-quotes

Comment: @X3MBoy Check my edit, I've been able to use a subshell :-)