# sed ubuntu vs mac regexp

Tags: regex, bash, macos, ubuntu, sed

This regexp i use on ubuntu with sed `'1p;/^\s/!d;/^\s*id/d'`. It lefts the first line untouched, removes empty lines and all, that don't begin with '{space}' or begin with '{blank}id'. On mac it lefts only the first line. How should regexp looks like on mac?
Example test.csv

```
   id  | code | color_code | 
-------+------+------------+
 11A00B|  15  | 9129102    |
 11A00C|  16  | 9129103    |
(2 rows)

   id  | code | color_code | 
-------+------+------------+
 11B00B|  25  | 9129152    |
 11B00C|  36  | 9129162    |
(2 rows)

   id  | code | color_code | 
-------+------+------------+
 11C00B|  22  | 9129107    |
 11C00C|  9   | 9129108    |
(2 rows)
```

After I call `sed -i '1p;/^\s/!d;/^\s*id/d' test.csv`
on ubuntu

```
   id  | code | color_code | 
 11A00B|  15  | 9129102    |
 11A00C|  16  | 9129103    |
 11B00B|  25  | 9129152    |
 11B00C|  36  | 9129162    |
 11C00B|  22  | 9129107    |
 11C00C|  9   | 9129108    |
```

on mac

```
   id  | code | color_code |
```

Comment: A much better fix is to change the program which produced these tables to not decorate the tables.  This looks like basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934264/how-to-hide-result-set-decoration-in-psql-output

Comment: I have no access to the program. It is 3rd party one.

Comment: It certainly looks like it's calling Postgres behind the scenes.  You could experiment with a wrapper to shadow `psql` or something similar, but this is going far outside the scope of your original question already.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu uses GNU `sed`, while OS X uses BSD `sed`. The quick answer is that `\s` is a GNU extension to recognize whitespace; use the standard `[[:space:]]` in its place and your command will work on both.

```
sed -i "bak" '1p;/^[[:space:]]/!d;/^[[:space:]]*id/d' test.csv
```

(Another difference is that BSD `sed` requires a suffix with the `-i` option, while it is optional with GNU.)

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed.